# Redmine notifications not being sent

Tags: docker, smtp, redmine

I'm running sameersbn/redmine in a docker container on a synology **NAS**. Here are some details on the installation:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                5.0.2.stable
  Ruby version                   2.7.5-p203 (2021-11-24) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  6.1.6
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               PostgreSQL
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
Redmine settings:
  Redmine theme                  Default
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.13.0
  Mercurial                      5.3.1
  Cvs                            1.12.13
  Bazaar                         3.0.2
  Git                            2.36.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

I configured smtp settings in config/configuration.yml using authentication: :login.

I believe configuration is correct, since I'm able to send a test email using the command

> **rake redmine:email:test[User] --trace**

But from within the web interface I'm not able to send a test email, receiving an error message:

```
  An error occurred while sending mail (Net::ReadTimeout with  #<Socket:(closed)>)
```

As a result, notifications are not being sent either.

On a side note, I tried another smtp server that doesn't require ssl/tls authentication. No problem sending test email there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you maybe configured test settings correctly, bur production wrong? There are multiple email configurations, based on ruby enviroment variable, production, test, development... Please check your config, on your image that's production env, and when you run test like rake from console that's test env...

Comment: The smtp settings are under "default:". Still I tried copying the same settings under "production:", no luck either.

Comment: rake redmine:email:test[User] RAILS_ENV="production" also successfully sends the test email.

Comment: then restart your docker container and retry...?

Comment: So this might be the issue, if for sending emails from the web interface a restart is required, but from rake command not. How can I start the container with the configuration.yml already edited?

Comment: refer to container docs... There must be some... It really depends upon how rails app is deployed, which servers are used, etc...

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar, you put me on the right track! The solution was to specify all the smtp environment variables when creating the container with the --env option. The list of available variables is here: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine#available-configuration-parameters